# How to ignore a define directive?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, pragma

I have the following problem. I'm writing **C** code that is dependent on someone else's code, which I am not able to make changes to. And in that code (that I'm not allowed to change) is a *define* preprocessor directive. My code is compiled before this other piece of code. And I need a way to circumvent this, so that my code is not affected by this *define* directive.

Is there a way to somehow tell the preprocessor to ignore all directives from now on?

What almost worked for me was the following pragma poison directive, but this unfortunately throws an error. Is there a way to suppress this error?

```
#pragma GCC poison define
```

I know that this is not an easy question to answer, but I'll really appreciate some help.

Comment: Can't you just use `#ifdef` together with `#undef`?

Comment: That's not possible because my preprocessor directives run before the other directives, so nothing is defined at that time...

Comment: @REACHUS His code is compiled before the other code.
Anyway, the preprocessor is not thought for that. Can't you just say: "hey, don't do this?"

Comment: @user3748798 I guess your define is included by a #include directive from the other code. You can create a new macro (for instance _MY_CODE_) and check it before define the poisoned directive

Comment: Yeah, you're right, my code is included from the other code. 
So you suggest I define a macro at the start of my code and then surround all my uses of "string" (because the define I want to avoid changes string to char* ) by ifdef and endif and then I eventually undef the macro? I'm not sure if it will work, but it seems really clever :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can do something like this: Assume that the problem is that the other code define `string` as `char *` and somewhere in the headers you need to include. You can define in your `c` files after the includes from the other code just:

```
#ifdef string
    #undef string
#endif
```

If your code include every times the same headers you can put all includes in one header and sanitize it at end: An example could be `other_include.h`:

```
#ifndef _OTHER_INCLUDE_H
#include <otherheader_a.h>
#include <otherheader_b.h>
#include <otherheader_c.h>

/*Sanitize string definition */

#ifdef string
    #undef string
#endif
#endif /* _OTHER_INCLUDE_H */
```

If you are not so lucky you must create a `sanitize.h` header and include it after all other include in your `c` files.

Moreover If you need some portion of code where disable the macro and recover it after :

```
#ifdef string
    #define _temp_string string
    #undef string
#endif
```

and when you want recover it

```
#ifdef _temp_string
    #define string _temp_string
    #undef _temp_string
#endif
```

That not really elegant but you can use it as a fine grain to make your subroutine safe.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to the portion of code, where #define string char* is defined - it is in the other code

Comment: @user3748798 I don't understand: you want use or not that directive in your code?

Comment: No, I don't want the define directive to affect my code

Comment: Ok I'll try to take i in account and modify my answer

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't really do a good job explaining the situation, but it's actually my code, that is the *subroutine* here, so the other code actually includes my code, not the other way around...

Comment: The sanitizing works. Thanks a lot, it did the trick and now I have a much better understanding of the preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that preprocessor directives run before the other directives, so nothing is defined at that time.

In this case I think the only solution would be to preprocess the file before the preprocessor stage using your own script and change the defined values to something that would suit your needs and would not have impact on your code. I don't think there is any better solution.

Comment: The directive that I'm trying to avoid is as follows:

#define string char*



and I want to be able to use string normally

Comment: @user3748798 You mean as a variable name or as C++'s `std::string`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean as std::string

Comment: Then I still suggest to write simple script to replace the problematic define with something that wouldn't contain `string`.